# Linq Equal comparer on a nullable integer field?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to figure out how to do an Equal on the following code:

```
Int32? testValue =  264;
MyTable.Where(a=>a.MyNullableNumberField.Equals(testValue));
```

I am stuck with the nullable field and I have to make the Equals method work. I know that I could use  "==" and it would work but in this case I have to use the Equals method.
The error that I get returned is:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Can you use `testValue.GetValueOrDefault()` or would the default value not be appropriate?

Comment: Why do you have to use `Equals`?

Comment: @stuartd That would result in `0 == null` being true, which it should not be, because `null` is different from the default value.

Comment: Apparently EF does not support `Equals`, so you simply **cannot** use it (*have to* doesn't matter when you work with code not written by you). Sounds like XY problem. Show the real use case in order to see if there is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to realize the difference between the `==` operator and `.Equals()`. Generally, the `==` operator compares references, while `.Equals()` is used to compare values. Of course, a comparison in the latter sense will only work with primitive types out of the box. Any object more complex than that (e.g. a user defined class) will need to have a custom `.Equals()` defined for it, to specify what exactly makes two instances of that object equal.

Normally, C# is smart enough to take care of things on its own when it comes to nullable numbers. However in certain cases (such as linq-to-entities) you have to push it in the right direction. This should work:

```
a.MyNullableNumberField.Value.Equals(testValue)
```

And to be totally safe, add a check right before to make sure the value exists:

```
 a.MyNullableNumberField.HasValue &&  a.MyNullableNumberField.Value.Equals(testValue)
```

Comment: `==` most certainly does *not* call `ReferenceEquals`.  It does whatever that type has overload it to do.  In the case of integers, as is being used here, they're comparing the values of the bits, just like `Equals` is.  Other types overlad `==` to do any number of things, just like they can override `Equals` to have *it* do whatever they want it to.  And of course in the case of an `Expression` converted into something else, the behavior of `==` or `Equals` in C# is simply irrelevant; it's up to the query provider to do whatever it wants and here it isn't doing a reference comparison.

Comment: The code that you're suggesting writing out is *precisely* what `==` is doing for you.  So not only is it *not* doing something radically different, contrary to your claims, it's doing *exactly what you want it to do*.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong answer in the context of LINQ to Entities. The "right direction" in LINQ to Entities is to use always `==` operator when present. It also supports `Nullable.Equals<T>` method, but it doesn't matter if you follow the previous rule.

Comment: I just did my best to work around OP's arbitrary limitation (they "have to" use `.Equals` and not `==`).